# Is $\beta \mathbb{D}\setminus \mathbb{D}$ a group?

Tags: gn.general-topology

NB the original question asked about $\beta\mathbb{D}$ rather than the corona, hence some of the initial comments.

---

Is there a group operation on $\beta \mathbb{D} \setminus \mathbb{D}$ extending complex multiplication on $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ is not cancelative as a monoid because of $0$, so there is no chance there is a group operation on anything that extend its multiplication...

Comment: But even for the cancellative semigroup $\mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$ (or $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$) no compatible group operation on $\beta(\mathbb D\setminus\{0\})$ (resp. $\beta(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})$ ) exists because of topological obstacles.

Comment: There is no continuous group operation. but such non continuous group structure exists, it is not completely clear what the OP is asking..

Comment: If the continuity is not required then at least there exists a natural semigroup operation on $\beta \mathbb D$, which exends the multiplication of complex numbers and is continuous by with respect to one variable (first, or second, depending on the construction).

Comment: Sorry about the badly formulated question. I had meant to ask the question with $\beta \mathbb{D}\setminus \mathbb{D}$, and wanted to know if that is a topological group.

Comment: The the answer is again "no" since $\beta\mathbb D\setminus\mathbb D$ has uncountable Souslin number (which follows from the existence of an uncountable almost disjoint family of subsets of $\omega$) whereas compact (more generally, $\sigma$-compact) topological groups have countable Souslin number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because $\beta\mathbb D$ and $\beta\mathbb D\setminus \mathbb D$ are not Dugundji compact (and not supercompact) whereas all compact topological groups are Dugundji compact according to a result of Uspenskii
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266010994_Topological_groups_and_Dugundji_compacta
and supercompact (by a result of Mills reproved by Kubis and Turek in http://link.springer.com/article/10.2478/s11533-011-0019-x).

Another reason why $\beta \mathbb D$ or $\beta\mathbb D\setminus\mathbb D$ cannot possess a group structure with continuous left (or right) shifts is that those spaces are not topologically homogeneous (because of the existence of weak P-points, for example).